# CiviCRM Webform : Select field used to use autofill

Tags: drupal, webform-civicrm

I want to use 3 fields (name, surname, phone number) to search existing contact and then autofill other fields.
I don't find how to specify how to map the CiviCRM field to search, nor how to define 3 fields used to search.

Is it possible? And how ?

Thank you for your help.

Regards.

Olivier.

Comment: Can you shed a bit more light on what you have tried. Based on your question I am unclear and hence hard to provide useful answer.

Comment: If you want to provide some sort of search functionality then perhaps using a Drupal View might be a better option.

Comment: @Graham that would make a good answer.

Comment: The goal is to allow event registration to known user, without using password and authentication. In the standard Civicrm/Webform integration, autofilling is based on the only Existing contact component using firsname and lastname. So the user must be identified, or any user can see all Civicrm contact. To allow known user to take advantage to autofilling, and not allow anyone to get all contact information, I want to add another field to identify the user.

Answer (score 2):

This is not exactly what you describe but may suit your purposes or at least give you something to go on.

1. In the CiviCRM tab of the webform builder, enable CiviCRM processing. For Contact 1, tick Existing Contact and a few other fields (try including some address fields for example).
2. Go to the Webform tab and click Edit next to the Existing Contact component. Set it to Autocomplete and then in the Contact Display Fields box, use Cntrl-Click to add a bunch of fields that match the ones you picked on the CiviCRM tab.

Go to View and now you should find that it works kind of like you describe. Start typing in the box and contacts should appear with First Name, Last name and email all in the box and when you pick one the other fields should populate.